# Rails 4 after_commit nested conditions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I would like to trigger the same function for `after_commit` on both `update` and `create` BUT I would like to apply a particular condition *only* for `update`.

For now, my only solution was to duplicate the function and make two different `after_commit` like this:

```
after_commit :my_method_on_update,
               on: :update,
               if: ->(foo) { foo.previous_changes.key?(:bar) }

after_commit :my_method_on_destroy, on: :destroy

def my_method_on_update
  # stuff
end

def my_method_on_destroy
  # same stuff here
end
```

Of course it works but it doesn't make the code DRY at all. I'm sure there is a better solution but I haven't found any relevant examples on the official rails [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit)

What I'd like is something like this:

```
after_commit :my_method,
               on: :update,
               if: ->(foo) { foo.previous_changes.key?(:bar) },
               on: destroy

def my_method
  # stuff
end
```

But there is an error with twice the declaration of `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases I would think that two separate `after_commit` hooks would be preferable – if there's a lot of shared code you could extract it into a third method that you call from both your update and create callbacks. However, if you really need to keep everything in one callback and one method then you can use [`transaction_include_any_action?`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Transactions/transaction_include_any_action%3F%60) to check whether the record has been created or updated:

```
after_commit :my_method

def my_method
  # do shared stuff for both create and update
  # ...
  if transaction_include_any_action?([:update])
    # do stuff only for create
  end
end
```

EDIT

So as I understand it, you want the callback to run on every `create` and `update`, but to do nothing if the action is `update` and a certain condition is fulfilled. You could still use `transaction_include_any_action?` and simply make the callback method return early if your condition is fulfilled, like this:

```
after_commit :my_method, on: [:create, :update]

def my_method
  return true if transaction_include_any_action?([:update]) && previous_changes.key?(:bar)
  # otherwise, continue
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer and your advice! However, I don't think your trick could help me here because I need to do the exact same thing over `create` or `update`. The only thing is that I _have to do nothing_ if the condition is not fulfil on `update`.

Comment: @MaxChrétien see my edit - you can just make the method do nothing like this! Although to be honest I still think that having two `after_commit` hooks would be clearer.

Comment: Perfect! Do you know if I can put the `if` condition on the same line as `after_commit`?

Comment: I suppose it would probably work! Give it a try, just make sure you include the receiver object like this: `unless: ->(foo) { foo.transaction_include_any_action?([:update]) && foo.previous_changes.key?(:bar)`. It might be nicer to extract that condition to a method on the model so you can say  e.g. `if: ->(foo) { foo.should_run_commit_hook? }`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @omnikron, here is my custom solution:

```
  after_commit :my_method,
               on: [:destroy, :update],
               unless: :exclude_commit_hook


  def exclude_commit_hook
    transaction_include_any_action?([:update]) && foo.previous_changes.key?(:bar)
  end

  def my_method
    # stuff
  end
```

Comment: Neat! Just one thing, in your case the `should_run_commit_hook` method actually returns `false` if the commit hook should be run, so the naming is a bit confusing. You could consider changing it to `exclude_commit_hook` or something else to make it clearer.

Comment: I did apply a better naming on my real code but I agree it was a bit confusing here. Thx for the help again!